# Synchronizing two threads - winapi

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, synchronization

Program below is a synchronization between two threads using a Mutex.

It compiles, works and prints what I want in order(alternating R/W for the 2 threads), but it crashes after it's done. Any idea why?

I think it has to do with closing `TName` handle, if I comment that part it doesn't crash, but I'd like to close opened handles.

```
HANDLE hMutex, hWriteDone, hReadDone;

int num, state;

void Writer()
{
    for(int x=10; x>=0; x--)
    {

        while (true)
        {

            if (WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED)
            {

                std::cout<<"In writing loop, no mutex!\n";

                ExitThread(0);
            }

            if (state == 0)
            {

                ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

                WaitForSingleObject(hReadDone, INFINITE);

                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        std::cout<<"Write done\n";

        num= x;

        state= 0;

        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

        PulseEvent(hWriteDone);
    }
}

void Reader()
{
    while(true)
    {

        if (WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED)
        {
            std::cout<<"In reader, no mutex!\n";

            ExitThread(0);

        }
        if (state == 1)
        {
            ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

            WaitForSingleObject(hWriteDone, INFINITE);

            continue;
        }

        if (num == 0)
        {

            std::cout<<"End of data\n";

            ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

            ExitThread(0);
        }
        else {

            std::cout<<"Read done\n";

            state=1;

            ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

            PulseEvent(hReadDone);

        }
    }
}

void main()
{

    HANDLE TName[2];
    DWORD ThreadID;

    state= 1;

    hMutex= CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    hWriteDone= CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    hReadDone= CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    TName[0]= CreateThread(NULL, 0,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Writer,
        NULL, 0, &ThreadID);

    TName[1]= CreateThread(NULL, 0,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Reader,
        NULL, 0, &ThreadID);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, TName, TRUE, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(TName);

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: When you call `WaitForSingleObject()`, you should be checking for `WAIT_OBJECT_0` instead of `WAIT_FAILED`. When dealing with mutexes,  `WaitForSingleObject()` could return `WAIT_ABANDONED`, which you are not handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lpStartAddress` parameter of [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx) is of type [`LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736.aspx). Which is a function pointer compatible with this signature:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter);
```

So you need to supply what the function expects. Your function `Reader` does not fit the bill. Change its signature to be like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI Reader(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    ....
}
```

And likewise for `Writer`.

Every time you cast something to suppress a compiler warning you are trading an easy to diagnose compile time error for a hard to diagnose run time error. That's a very bad trade. So, as a general rule, don't use casts. Sometimes you'll need to break that rule, but do so in full understanding of what you are doing.

Your `main` function also has a somewhat bogus signature. If you don't want to process arguments, then you should declare it like this:

```
int main()
```

Since you ignore the thread ID, you may as well pass `NULL` for the final parameter of `CreateThread`.

This also is wrong:

```
CloseHandle(TName);
```

The parameter of `CloseHandle` is of type `HANDLE`. You are passing a pointer to an array. You need to do this:

```
CloseHandle(TName[0]);
CloseHandle(TName[1]);
```

The `Writer` function does not return a value. The compiler warns you about that, if you enable sufficient warnings. You should certainly do so.

Comment: While this did work, my program still crashes. Even though this might've solved a problem, it didn't solve the original problem.

Comment: I'm sorry that my answer is such a disappointment to you. You did fix both thread procedures?

Comment: It's not. It seems that if I do `CloseHandle(TName[0]);
 CloseHandle(TName[1]);` it works. Why so?

Comment: My answer deals with that too now.

Comment: It depends how you do it. Here you could have added an extra section as an addition to the original. Otherwise the existing answers are out of place. You could have said, "I fixed the thread procedure declarations, but still encounter a crash a shutdown".

Comment: Also if your code is crashing, it's best to provide a stack trace. That would have narrowed things down from the start.

Answer (score 2):

You should never cast a function pointer. Remove the (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) casts from your code, fix the compiler errors, and try again. Never use casts to quell compiler errors.

Comment: Why should I never cast a fct. pointer? I could do that, but I want to know why.

Comment: Casting only tells the compiler to shut up, it doesn't actually fix anything. But what if the compiler's warnings are actually valid? If CreateThread wants a certain function signature, you must provide it.

Comment: ... and if you provide the wrong function signature, it can cause oddball crashes, often related to the stack. In this case your code probably crashes because your functions don't leave the stack in the state that CreateThread expects.

Comment: Windows passes the LPVOID parameter to your thread function. That's on the stack. When your thread returns it probably attempts to return to the wrong address: the parameter.